# Mysql Remote Connection Failed

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu-18.04

Im trying with php to connect my remote server's mysql im getting this error:

**"Database Connection Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] connection refused"**

I made what said in that page : https://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/enable-mysql-remote-access-ubuntu/

this is my setting now: [image]

and ofcourse restarted mysql.

ANd its still saying same error "Database Connection Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] connection refused"

What can i do else?

this is my connection setting: [image]

When i try port 3306 same error. What can cause that?

ps: also this is a remote connection from a hosting shared to my dedicated server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

it was about cloudflare or other proxies. Fixed.